# Why isn't my base64-encoded image being recognized by this API POST method?

Tags: python, post, base64, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to use an API to upload a JPEG image. Here is the method information: [Add file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va9ZR.png)

You can see it requires two parameters: "name" and "file_data" (the base64-encoded contents of the file).

Here's where I'm at so far:

```
file_data = base64.b64encode(requests.get(images[0]).content) 
response = client.fileManager.upload({"name": "test.jpg", "file_data": 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + str(file_data)})
print(response)
```

And I'm receiving this error response:

```
"Invalid Resource","status":400,"detail":"Error parsing image: The uploaded file is not an image, but has an image extension."
```

I was originally trying to use just "file_data": str(file_data) and was receiving the same exact error, so I tried a data URI as you can see. Also, if I substitute "test.txt" for "test.jpg" then the upload function works fine so that must mean the issue is something with the file_data.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding .decode('utf8') at the end.

```
file_data = base64.b64encode(requests.get(images[0]).content).decode('utf8')
```

I add that when I convert a matplotlib figure to an PNG as shown below.

```
# Convert plot to PNG image
pngImage = io.BytesIO()
FigureCanvas(fig).print_png(pngImage)

# Encode PNG image to base64 string
pngImageB64String = "data:image/png;base64,"
pngImageB64String += base64.b64encode(pngImage.getvalue()).decode('utf8')
```